# composite Problem with background

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes

there is 2 thing, how do I rid of the black void in the background? I want to put anything for my project. and second, I experimented then Moneky's outline joining the "cubes test". outline only for monkeys, and cubes test" for the background so it is not supposed to have a background. here is the file.
[image]

[image]

\